# MySQL joining 6 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning MySQL and starting to get my head around it a bit but I need to do a certain query and hoping someone can help. I think it's fairly simple for a guru.
Database is in MySQL.

My database has the following 6 tables:

course

```
| id | coursename  |
|  1 | mathematics |
|  2 | physics     |
|  3 | chemistry   |
```

student

```
| id | name        |
|  1 | John        |
|  2 | Mary        |
|  3 | Peter       |
```

gradesitems

```
|  id  | courseid    | itemname            |
|  109 | 1           | mathematicscourse   |
|  110 | 1           | mathematicsquiz     |
|  111 | 2           | physicscoursecourse |
|  112 | 2           | physicsquiz         |
|  113 | 3           | chemistrycourse     |
|  114 | 3           | chemistryquiz       |
```

gradesscores

```
| id | itemid | studentid | score |
|  1 |  109   |  1        | 64    |
|  2 |  110   |  1        |       |
|  3 |  111   |  1        | 90    |
|  4 |  112   |  1        | 10    |
|  5 |  113   |  1        |       |
|  6 |  114   |  1        | 78    |
```

courseitems

```
| id | studentid |
| 23 | 1         |
| 24 | 1         |
| 25 | 2         |
```

itemcompletion

```
| id | courseitemid  | completionstate |
|  1 | 23            | 1               |
|  2 | 24            | 1               |
|  3 | 25            | 1               |
|  3 | 26            | 1               |
```

and my desired output is as follow:

```
| studentname | course      | item                | grade | completion |
| John        | mathematics | mathematicscourse   | 64    | 1          |
| John        | mathematics | mathematicsquiz     |       |            |
| John        | physics     | physicscoursecourse | 90    | 1          |
| John        | physics     | physicsquiz         | 10    |            |
| John        | chemistry   | chemistrycourse     |       |            |
| John        | chemistry   | chemistryquiz       | 78    | 1          |
```

if that makes sense!

EDIT:

Apologies, here is how far ive come:

```
SELECT u.name, c.id, c.coursename, compl.completionstate
FROM course AS c
JOIN user AS u
JOIN itemcompletion AS compl
```

:(

Comment: what effort have you done?

Comment: sorry i have added the bit that I have done, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step back and slow down a moment... although you are missing something to associate grades with the completed status from what I see, writing a query at its basics is...

```
select list, of, fields
   from oneOrMoreTables
   where SomeCondition...
```

Now, first thing, ignore the actual columns you want (for now), and take a look at the tables.  Write the "FROM" clause first with all the related JOIN conditions showing the relationships between them.  For now, all JOINS (INNER JOIN meaning record must appear on both left and right side table/alias reference.

When I write queries, I try to always "alias" the table for simplified readability when building out column names.  Also, ALWAYS try to refer to fields as ALIAS.COLUMN you can get bad results if two tables have the same column name and you accidentally forget to qualify it with the alias.  It will join to itself and always return true (I've seen it happen to others).

Anyhow, the FROM clause.  This is for the relationship between tables REGARDLESS OF CRITERIA.  So, I'm starting with the course, then moving on from there.  Notice how I've done the indentation to show visually, and (for me mentally) where tableA (left-side) relates to tableB (right-side)... also important when you get to LEFT JOIN (vs right-join).

```
select....
   from
      course c    <--  "c" is the alias for course table reference
         join gradesitems gi   <-- "gi" is alias for gradesitems
            ON c.id = gi.courseid
            join gradesscores gs   <-- "gs" is alias for gradesscores
               ON gi.id = gs.itemid
               join student s    <-- "s" is alias for student table
                  ON gs.studentid = s.id
```

Notice too that I refer to the left-table first then the right-table for each of the ON clauses of the join... How are they related, by their respective columns.

Now, grab the columns you want FOR your query... These too will be alias.column referenced

```
SELECT
      c.coursename,
      gi.itemname,
      s.name,
      gs.score
   from
      course c
         join gradesitems gi
            ON c.id = gi.courseid
            join gradesscores gs
               ON gi.id = gs.itemid
               join student s
                  ON gs.studentid = s.id
```

So this gets you MOST of the data elements you want.  As I mentioned, it appears you are missing something from your courseItems and ItemsCompletion.  Nothing to tie back to the specific course task/student (such as in the gradesitems table).  I have no idea what relates the courseItems to the specific task/grade student 1 took... they took multiple classes and different tests.  I cannot just assume the first entry for the first entry, second for the second, so those tables may need to be adjusted, or just left out completely.  If no grade for the grades-items, it's not completed.

Comment: thank you, i am going to mark this answered for now and work through you example. I will see how far I get and then maybe I will ask again :)

Comment: but the way you have broken it down is going to be extremely helpful

Comment: @user1525612, this, in conjunction with better table structure and normalization from smcjones's answer should get you on a better track downstream.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should look more deeply into [INNER JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form). It doesn't take long to get your head around them but it does exactly what you want it to do. Your code, specifically, is missing the ON clause which is what allows you to make the link. AKA something like:

```
SELECT student.name, course.name FROM student
INNER JOIN schedule ON schedule.FK_student_id=student.id
INNER JOIN course ON course.id=schedule.FK_course_id
```

My second point is that I was unable to use your tables OR your query. Your query in your example references a user table you have not referenced once in your tables. Your tables are further designed to be built for failure. One of the hardest things I had to learn was to really understand how relational databases work.

If you want to make complicated transactions, I would highly advice that you take several hours to brush up on database normalization. I believe this could really do with [Fourth Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form). Although I won't be able to do it justice, the idea is that you don't want to have "non-trivial keys". At each table, ask yourself the question: "Is there a reason I am separating my data?"

My third point is that I can't really even give you concrete examples of where your non-trivial keys are, because you have not named them very clearly. This is confusing for me, and speaking out of experience, having created similar nightmares on my own, I can guarantee you that when you go back and look at this a month from now, **even if** you get the queries to work, you will have no idea what the tables are doing.

For that, I will suggest some concrete naming standards:

- You don't need to have any specific naming standard, but you do need one. I use FK_[table_name]_id to reference Foreign keys. Currently, you have an foreign key in `gradescores` that is `itemid`, but you have no table called `item`. Instead you have `courseitems` and `gradeitems`. I know you can tell me where it belongs, but if your table is built well, then you will be able to just show someone your structure and they'll understand what goes where!
- Consider your table like so: Is there a one-to-one, or a one-to-many, relationship here? It is highly recommended that you have only one join table.

So your table could look more like:

table `student`

```
id | name
```

table `course`

```
id | name

table assignment
id | name
```

table `completion`

```
id | status
1  | complete
2  | incomplete
```

table `grade`

```
id | grade
1  | A
2  | B
.. | ..
```

table `reportcard`

```
id | FK_student_id | FK_course_id | FK_assignment_id | FK_completion_id | FK_grade_id
```

Of course, you don't need to do this, but I can guarantee you, from personal experience, the longer you put it off the harder it is to fix it. Once you get it it is FAR easier to build queries - even ones more complicated than these - and your applications will be built really quickly.

Comment: thanks, i will have to read up a bit more i think, i appreciate your words of wisdom!

Comment: upvoted... as my answer helps the user to understand more of writing the queries and seeing the relationships, your answer definitely helps them to get a better-up on understanding normalization and fix now rather than later.